# Custom Renderer: Custom Renderer for rounded buttons

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, portable-class-library, custom-renderer

I am developing a cross-platform app using PCL Xamarin Forms Project. My app will run on ios, android, windows 10 and windows 8.1 desktops.

I want to make a custom renderer for button control in xamarin forms in which I can specify following properties from xaml page and from code behind also-

1. Border Color
2. Border Width
3. Border Radius
4. Background Color
5. Text Color
6. Text font size, color, attribute like bold.
7. Height and Width of Button

I have tried the normal button control of xamarin forms but in that border radius does not work in android and on hover button color changes in windows 10.
So how can I achieve this?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Jason Is my question still unclear to you?

Comment: "I need..." is not a question.

Answer (score 1):

In Android the `RadiusProperty` stops working only with `AppCompat` its a [known issue](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/180130)

## AppCompat

If you want to use a normal button and AppCompat at the same time you will need to inherit from Button and register a `CustomRenderer`.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(RoundButton), typeof(RoundButtonRenderer))]
namespace Project.Droid.Renderers
{
    public class RoundButtonRenderer : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.ButtonRenderer
    {
        ButtonDrawable _backgroundDrawable;
        Drawable _defaultDrawable;
        bool _drawableEnabled;

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                if (_backgroundDrawable != null)
                {
                    _backgroundDrawable.Dispose();
                    _backgroundDrawable = null;
                }
            }

            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }


        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Button> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null && _drawableEnabled)
            {
                _drawableEnabled = false;
                _backgroundDrawable.Reset();
                _backgroundDrawable = null;
            }
            UpdateDrawable();
        }



        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_drawableEnabled &&
                (e.PropertyName == VisualElement.BackgroundColorProperty.PropertyName || e.PropertyName == Xamarin.Forms.Button.BorderColorProperty.PropertyName || e.PropertyName == Xamarin.Forms.Button.BorderRadiusProperty.PropertyName ||
                e.PropertyName == Xamarin.Forms.Button.BorderWidthProperty.PropertyName))
            {
                _backgroundDrawable.Reset();
                Control.Invalidate();
            }

            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
        }

        private void UpdateDrawable()
        {
            if (Element.BackgroundColor == Color.Default)
            {
                if (!_drawableEnabled)
                    return;

                if (_defaultDrawable != null)
                    Control.SetBackground(_defaultDrawable);

                _drawableEnabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                if (_backgroundDrawable == null)
                    _backgroundDrawable = new ButtonDrawable();

                _backgroundDrawable.Button = Element;

                if (_drawableEnabled)
                    return;

                if (_defaultDrawable == null)
                    _defaultDrawable = Control.Background;

                Control.SetBackground(_backgroundDrawable.GetDrawable());
                _drawableEnabled = true;
            }

            Control.Invalidate();
        }
    }


    public class ButtonDrawable : IDisposable
    {
        object _backgroundDrawable;

        PropertyInfo ButtonProperty;
        public Xamarin.Forms.Button Button
        {
            get
            {
                return (Xamarin.Forms.Button)ButtonProperty.GetMethod.Invoke(_backgroundDrawable, null);
            }
            set
            {
                ButtonProperty.SetMethod.Invoke(_backgroundDrawable, new object[] { value });
            }
        }

        public ButtonDrawable()
        {
            _backgroundDrawable = typeof(Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ButtonRenderer).Assembly.CreateInstance("Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ButtonDrawable");
            this.ResetMethod = _backgroundDrawable.GetType().GetMethod("Reset", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
            this.DisposeMethod = _backgroundDrawable.GetType().GetMethod("Dispose", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
            this.ButtonProperty = _backgroundDrawable.GetType().GetProperty("Button", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
        }

        MethodInfo ResetMethod;
        public void Reset()
        {
            ResetMethod.Invoke(_backgroundDrawable, null);
        }

        MethodInfo DisposeMethod;
        public void Dispose()
        {
            DisposeMethod.Invoke(_backgroundDrawable, null);
        }

        public Android.Graphics.Drawables.Drawable GetDrawable()
        {
            return _backgroundDrawable as Android.Graphics.Drawables.Drawable;
        }
    }
}
```

## Without AppCompat

if you want to remove AppCompat you must do two things

Your `MainActivity` must inherit now from `global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity`
and your style usually in `resources/values/styles.xml` must inherit from a non-AppCompat style like `android:Theme.Material`

```
<resources>
  <!-- inherit from the material theme -->
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
    <!-- Main theme colors -->
    <!--   your app branding color for the app bar -->
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
    <!--   darker variant for the status bar and contextual app bars -->
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_dark</item>
    <!--   theme UI controls like checkboxes and text fields -->
    <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Do Border radius works on IOS? I have not tried it yet.

Comment: Never had a problem with it, but havent tried on any windows platform

Comment: I have tried the normal button control in Windows10 and 8.1 Works fine!!!

Comment: @Sonali if you put an incorrect amount on `BorderRadius` bigger than half the height of it, it will be a little wrong

Comment: ok, I will keep that in mind, so making a custom renderer for android only will solve my problem right?

Comment: yeah, it will probably solver your problem, deactivate AppCompat might resolve it as well

Comment: Where can I find AppCompat in xamarin? Is it activated by default? I am need to android development.

Comment: In your android's MainActivity it probably inherits from `global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity` so you have to make it inherit from `FormsActivity` (not sure if it is this name) and you will have to change your Theme as well for a non AppCompat theme

Comment: In my mainactivity.cs `public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity` is there. In theme what changes I have to make?

Comment: you must change to `public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity` then your style must inherit from a non AppCompat Style like `@android:style/Theme.Material`

Answer (score 1):

I using these properties on my app and for me works fine.
I am using these properties with "Styles".

Example:

```
<Style x:Key="buttonStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="{DynamicResource Snow}"/>
    <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{DynamicResource LightBlue}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="{DynamicResource LightBlue}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderRadius" Value="15"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderWidth" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold" />
  </Style>
```

My Button:

```
<Button Text="Login" Command="{Binding LoginCommand}" Style="{DynamicResource buttonStyle}" />
```

[Xamarin Styles](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/)

Comment: I have tried it but in android it does not work. Button comes with no border and no rounded corners

Comment: Try clear de project and compile again. Maybe is only a trash on the files. I´m using this in my current project and i haven´t problems.

Comment: I try this, getting error: Namespace prefix 'x' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Create a style in Content Page resource and and add this style in button.
> 2. CornerRadius is must be half of HeightRequest and WidthRequest.
> 3. This is for Xamarin.Forms >= 3.4. Now BorderRadius convert into CornerRadius.

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="myRoundbutton" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Green"/>
            <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="BorderColor" Value="Blue"/>
             <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="35"/>
            <Setter Property="HeightRequest" Value="70" />
            <Setter Property="WidthRequest" Value="70"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderWidth" Value="2"/>
            <Setter Property="FontAttributes" Value="Bold" />
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>

<ContentPage.Content>
      <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="Fill" 
                   VerticalOptions="Fill">

          <Button Image="myBtn3.png" 
                  Command="{Binding LoginCommand}" 
                  Style="{DynamicResource myRoundbutton}" />

      </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```